# What's the value of the integral $\int_{-4}^{4}(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \delta(2t))\sin(t)\mathrm{d} t$ ..where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta

Tags: continuous-signals

Can it be solved like
$$\begin{align}\int_{-4}^{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \delta(2t)\sin(2t)\mathrm{d}t &=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\int_{-4}^{4}\delta(t)\sin(2t)\mathrm{d}t\quad ^*\\ 
&=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}t} = 0\quad ^{**}\\
\end{align}$$
$^*$ Since linear operations can be interchanged.

$^{**}$ Since $\int_{-4}^{4}\delta(t)\sin(2t)\mathrm{d} t= \sin 0=0$.

Comment: [dollars](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076)

Comment: This question is not relevant to signal processing and should instead be asked at the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Vote to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about signal processing.

Comment: Seems like signal processing to me.  Math Exchange is more for talking about Dirac deltas not being real functions etc https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67293/2206  Does seem like a homework problem though.